# Pass a list to dapper to filter or exclude items, Postgres, where not in

Tags: c#, postgresql, dapper

C#
To filter by Ids on a postgreSql query using dapper you can use "= ANY (:myList)" for example

```
await using var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(_dbContext.Database.GetConnectionString());
    await conn.ExecuteAsync(@"
        UPDATE books
        SET discount = :discount
        WHERE author_id = :authorIds
        AND book_id = ANY(:bookIds);
", new { discount = discountVal, authorId = author, bookIds = BookIdList });
```

Which is equivalent to using IN.

But in the case when you need to exclude is not possible to use the any (<> ANY()) because it does an OR operation for each ID.

Using a simple NOT IN brings type issues in this case because my ids are uuid, same case will be for int if you try to convert your lost to string,

```
tried

AND book_id <> ANY(:bookIds);

also
AND book_id NOT IN (:bookIds); with and without Parenthesis
also
```

```
    AND book_id NOT IN (:bookIds);
```

", new { discount = discountVal, authorId = author, bookIds = String.Join(",",BookIdList.Select(x=>$"('{x}')")) });

```
which brings type comparison issues like "Npgsql.PostgresException: 42883: operator does not exist: uuid <> text"
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying a few array operations, I was able to make it work like this

```
await using var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(_dbContext.Database.GetConnectionString());
    await conn.ExecuteAsync(@"
        UPDATE books
        SET discount = :discount
        WHERE author_id = :authorIds
        AND book_id NOT IN (SELECT unnest(:bookIds));
", new { discount = discountVal, authorId = author, bookIds = BookIdList });
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).